# How to use Github webhooks

Tags: github, hook

I need your help !

How to download the updated files in github project (not all files) using git hook api when project members commiting the new version ?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to [register a webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) for your repo, which will emit a [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) that you would listen.
You can register a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) for [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)

The listener depends on your local environment.
For example, you have [Introducing Gith - GitHub WebHooks For Node](http://bocoup.com/weblog/introducing-gith-github-webhooks-for-node/), which can filter the payloads by payload type: repository, branch, file or tag

You have simpler listeners, for [instance on in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14536992/6309).
Again, the specifics of the listener and what you can do when you receive the message (like a `git pull` to download what has changed) depend on your particular environment.