# How to get feed from Github file modifications?

Tags: github

Is there a way to get a feed of updates to a file in a Github repo? Note I don't own the repo, I just wanted to be informed when a file (the release notes) changes and ideally have that in an MS Teams channel.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub feeds](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/feeds/) are for a repository as a whole, or for user activity.

There is no feed on a file-by-file basis.

You would need to install a [push event webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) listener, as [I mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950094/6309), in order to pull, [get the list of files of that pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522692/6309), and send you a notification of your file is part of the pull.
In short: a manual feed notification mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Every file has its commits RSS.

In example for the file

https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/news/changelog-1.4.md

the commits feed RSS is this

https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/commits/main/news/changelog-1.4.md.atom