# Listen for and receive payload from github webhook in Python/Django

Tags: django, post, github, django-views, csrf

My problem is very much like the one here:  [How do I receive Github Webhooks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536992/how-do-i-receive-github-webhooks-in-python)

The difference is, I am sure about my framework, that being Django. 
I have been able to register webhook for a particular repository, and did port forwarded using ngrok. The Payload delivered gets a 403 response because of csrf validation error, I am not being able to resolve it.
Also, how do I continually listen for the payload JSON and store it in my database as and when it comes?

The response at github webhook:
https://imageshack.com/i/exZfoM8Ip

403 Forbidden as shown by ngrok: https://imageshack.com/i/ipnzhQLVp

*NOTE: Links are now down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no concept of "continually listening" in a web app, because that's exactly what web apps always do. You simply set up a URL pointing to a view.

And as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views) says, you can exempt a view from CSRF enforcemnt by using the `@csrf_exempt` decorator.