# Ideas needed - scripting access reports for folders

Tags: box-api

Have a group of users who would like to receive access reports (download, view, etc.) for content they own under a set of folders.  This set of folders isn't super dynamic, so in theory we could maintain a static list, but would love to make this fully automated.

My initial thought was to have the users add a special tag to a folder they want to include in the report.  Then I could search all enterprise events for items affecting items which live under a tagged folder and spit it out into a CSV file.

Maybe I can search for all tagged folders, gather the folder id's then loop through my enterprise events looking for any item with an ancestor folder that matches?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach makes sense. You can get this data using the Events API as you described. Another approach would be using webhooks.

**Approach One: Events API**

1. [Add a tag to the folder](https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Your-Content/Tagging-Content-In-Box/ta-p/693) you want to monitor.
2. Use the Search API to return folders that match this tag.

   /search?query=TAG_EXAMPLE&type=folder&content_types=tags
3. Use the Events API to get all events.

   /events?stream_position=0
4. Parse for Downloaded and Previewed events, where the event is for file that has a matching parent folder from the folder list in Step 2.

**Approach Two: Webhooks**

1. [Add a tag to the folder](https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Your-Content/Tagging-Content-In-Box/ta-p/693) you want to monitor.
2. Use the Search API to return folders that match that tag.

   /search?query=TAG_EXAMPLE&type=folder&content_types=tags
3. [Create a webhook in Box](https://developers.box.com/webhooks/) that notifies an external application when a file is downloaded or previewed. Add a parameter to webhook for the file's parent folder.
4. [Create an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536992/how-do-i-receive-github-webhooks-in-python) that listens for these webhooks.
5. Parse for events, where the event is for a file that has a matching parent folder from the folder list in Step 2.