# Deploying a test web app for each GitHub pull request

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

Is it possible for GitHub to trigger a new test deployment when a pull request is submitted? I'd like for it to create a new folder on the server (Azure preferred) so that a test URL (e.g. http://testserver.com/PR602/) is generated that we can refer to in the pull request.

This would allow anyone to test a pull request without having to clone the repo, check out the branch, and build it locally.

In my initial research I found that Travis CI can [deploy all branches](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/azure-web-apps#Branch-to-deploy-from), but I'm not clear how this would be triggered. Do I have to write a custom app that's triggered by [pull request web hooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent)? I'm hoping someone has discovered a simpler method.

Comment: Check [this document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/). It's possible and quite easy to set up.

Comment: Thanks, @JackZeng. Unless I'm missing something all of the instructions are for deploying a specific branch. I want to automatically deploy every pull request to a new folder, regardless of what branch it originates from.

Comment: oh, I see. You want every pull request to have a unique URL, so that every user can test his/her commits individually. Sorry, I misunderstood you. That's an interesting question. I will do some digging, and see what I can do.

Comment: @MikeWheaton Have you found a solution for this? I'm interested in deploying every PR as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to write a custom app that's triggered by pull request web hooks?

Yes, or find someone else who has happened to have written the exact webhook handler you need.

Writing a webhook handler isn't terribly much work.  If you don't want to integrate it with your current app, you can use a micro-framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to do this in only a few lines of code.

---

Coming back to this in 2022, there is now also the option of [Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions), which is a first-party CI service.  Actions provides a framework for defining what things to do when certain triggers happen, and there's [an extensive marketplace of drop-in components](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions), so you may be able to do all of your triggering of other systems without writing any custom code or running a webserver to listen to webhooks.

Comment: I'm trying to do just that for running PR validation checks with Bamboo build plans. Is there an example you can point me to?

Comment: Bamboo already has webhook handlers set up; you just need to [connect GitHub to them](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/212403/how-to-trigger-bamboo-from-github).

Comment: Thanks, but it's not clear to me how this is can be integrated with GitHub for PR validation checks. How can Bamboo create a build branch specific to the GitHub commit that triggered it? And how can Bamboo send build statuses (pending, failed, passed) back to GitHub? It seems I need a web app for this...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Bamboo "creating a build branch" - it should instead be testing an existing branch.  Whatever script you have Bamboo run to test things should include a call to the GitHub status API.  This, however, is getting rather far from the topic of this question, so you should probably open one of your own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208801/add-validation-checks-for-github-pull-requests